# how to properly use Veulidate along with vuex in vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate, formvalidation-plugin

In the following code, I use two methods on input to update both state and apply vuelidate validation rules, now validation rules doesn't applied properly, `$v.newEmloyeeName.$dirty` get's always true. How to fix this so both state gets updated and validation rules applied on input? I'm using vue 2

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Employee Name *"
  @input="setNewEmployeeName; setName()" 
  :value="newEmployeeName">

<div v-if="$v.newEmloyeeName.$dirty">
  <div class="text-danger" role="alert" v-if="!$v.newEmloyeeName.required">
    <small>Employee Name is required</small>
  </div>
</div>
...

<script>
import { required} from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
import {mapMutations, mapState} from vuex;
export default{
validations: { newEmloyeeName: {required}},
computed: { ...mapState('addemployee',['newEmployeeName'])},
methods:{
  ...mapMutations('addemployee',['setNewEmployeeName']),
  setName(){this.$v.newEmployeeName.$touch()}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`v-on` directive accepts expression or callback function as event handler. Considring that `click` is a method, `@click="click"` and `@click="click($event)"` behave the same way, with the latter being explicit.

`setNewEmployeeName; setName()` is JS expression and it behaves like it would be evaluated outside the template; `setNewEmployeeName` is not called and is a no-op, while it should be provided with field value as an argument.

It's a good practice to not distribute JS code between `template` and `script` parts of a component. Instead, it can be:

```
@input="setName"
```

and

```
setName(event){
  this.setNewEmployeeName(event.target.value);
  this.$v.newEmployeeName.$touch()
}
```

Comment: Now I've applied single call on @input as you shown, but it also behaves the same. when setName() gets an event, the error message always shown, to be specific $v.newEmloyeeName.$dirty get's always true when this.$v.newEmployeeName.$touch() gets executed. however without vuex, vuelidate working fine, what to do?